# google analytics api to get ecommerce transaction and add to cart details in php

Tags: php, api, google-analytics, transactions, e-commerce

I have added google analytics script in my site to track ecommerce transaction . I need to get the transaction details in my another admin panel. is there any api in php to get the ecommerce data .I have added the below script in my site

```
ga('ec:addProduct', {
    'id': product.product_id,
    'name': product.product_name,
     'category': product.category_name,
    'brand': product.brandname,
    'variant': product.color,
     'price': product.product_price,
    'quantity': 1
 });
   ga('ec:setAction', 'add');
   ga('send', 'event', 'UX', 'click', 'add to cart');
```

Comment: Another admin panel - Your Ecommerce App Admin Panel or another Google Analytics account?

Comment: I need to get the ecommerce transaction and details to display in  a reporting admin panel . i need to get mutiple site tracking details in the admin . not a single tracking site

Comment: Then your only option is to POST your ECommerce transaction data to your admin backend with an Ajax call and handle it appropriately to display it in your reporting admin panel. If you are using a specific E-Commerce product then you will have to look into the documentation and check if there's an inbuilt feature/plugin that matches your requirement otherwise you will have to do code it yourself.

Comment: Google analytics already providing the information in api. But i am not getting the report data when  using the API .